# call a method inside a class from a service

Tags: android, methods, service

i have been using this code to call my method from my service from inside another class. However, it only works with the method for showing notifications, and gives me this error when i try to call any other method besides that "**Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getSystemService(String) from the type Activity**"

*service*

```
package com.example.notifypro;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

public class NotifyService extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        MainActivity.mehtodName(context);
        // ... do what you need to do here...
    }

}
```

*MainActivity.java* (the method which is getting called with no problems)

```
public static void mehtodName(Context context) {
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
            new Intent(context, MainActivity.class), 0);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
            context).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("My notification")
            .setContentText("Hello World!");
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
    mBuilder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND);
    mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mNotificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());

}
```

*The method i am trying to call*

```
private static void MyMethod() {
ConnectivityManager cmanager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(this.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo info = cmanager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (info != null && info.isConnected()) {
        if (info.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI) {
        //  img_b1.setImageResource(R.drawable.index2);
        } else if (info.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE) {
            //img_b2.setImageResource(R.drawable.index2);
        }
    } else {
        //img_b3.setImageResource(R.drawable.index2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pass context to your method

```
private static void MyMethod(Context context) {
        ConnectivityManager cmanager = (ConnectivityManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo info = cmanager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (info != null && info.isConnected()) {
            if (info.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI) {
                // img_b1.setImageResource(R.drawable.index2);
            } else if (info.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE) {
                // img_b2.setImageResource(R.drawable.index2);
            }
        } else {
            // img_b3.setImageResource(R.drawable.index2);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

pass context in MyMethod()

```
private static void MyMethod(Context context)
```

use Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE inplace of this.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE

```
ConnectivityManager cmanager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
```

Comment: use `Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE`, make sure to use Context class, not variable